# Extract keys from string hash

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following hash string:

```
arr = ["{:id=>1, :name=>\"a\"}", "{:id=>2, :name=>\"b\"}"]
```

How can I parse the data and get all id keys in a array like this: [1,2]

Thanks.

Comment: `arr.map { |s| s[6..-1].to_i }`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Ruby hashes which need to be evaluated, so use eval within a map:

```
arr.map{|hash| eval(hash)[:id]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this array of strings doesn't seem to be exactly valid JSON, you can parse out the ids by doing something like the following:

```
arr = ["{:id=>1, :name=>\"a\"}", "{:id=>2, :name=>\"b\"}"]

arr.map { |x| x.split(":id=>").last.split(",").first.to_i }
# => [1, 2]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

This is an array of JSON strings. You can use JSON.parse to parse them

```
arr = ["{:id=>1, :name=>\"a\"}", "{:id=>2, :name=>\"b\"}"]
ids = arr.map do |raw| # iterate on each string
  JSON.parse(raw)[:id] # parse and extract the id
end

puts ids # => [1,2]
```

Comment: i didn't downvote but, i had put a similar answer without checking it. its not proper json so it doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, did not realise this was not JSON. Goot catch.

Comment: The values of `:name` are not objects (not strings).